# Property doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

ok may be a simple one but this has me puzzled

i have an SFC defined using

```
export default defineComponent({
    setup(): { args: Args; preview: Point[] } {
        const args = new Args();
        const preview: Point[] = [];
        args.values.push(...args.shape.shapeArgs.map((d) => d.default));
        return { args, preview: preview };
    },
    computed: {
        previewSize() {
            return {
                width: (Math.max(1, ...this.preview.map((p) => p.x)) + 40) * 10,
                height: (Math.max(1, ...this.preview.map((p) => p.y)) + 40) * 10,
            };
        },
...
```

however it wont run because

```
TS2339: Property 'preview' does not exist on type 'ComponentPublicInstance<{} | {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, EmitsOptions, {} | {}, {}, false, ComponentOptionsBase<{} | {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, ComponentOptionsMixin, ComponentOptionsMixin, EmitsOptions, string, {}>>'.
  Property 'preview' does not exist on type '{ $: ComponentInternalInstance; $data: {}; $props: {} | {}; $attrs: Record<string, unknown>; $refs: Record<string, unknown>; $slots: Readonly<InternalSlots>; ... 7 more ...; $watch(source: string | Function, cb: Function, options?: WatchOptions<...> | undefined): WatchStopHandle; } & ... 4 more ... & ComponentCustom...'.
    56 |        previewSize() {
    57 |            return {
  > 58 |                width: (Math.max(1, ...this.preview.map((p) => p.x)) + 40) * 10,
       |                                            ^^^^^^^
```

as preview clearly is defined i'm puzzled as to why it doesn't exist

Comment: that's interesting because literally every example i have found it uses type inference to do the typing with nothing explicit so it is clearly supposed to be able to pick it up

Comment: thanks to @Francesco Vattiato , looks like i had my wires crossed and had mixed the options and composition together in a way they shouldn't be mixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from the [Vue3 typescript documentation about computed](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#typing-computed)

```
import { defineComponent, ref, computed } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'CounterButton',
  setup() {
    let count = ref(0)

    // read-only
    const doubleCount = computed(() => count.value * 2)

    const result = doubleCount.value.split('') // => Property 'split' does not exist on type 'number'
  }
})
```

You may try to do something like:

```
export default defineComponent({
    setup(): { args: Args; preview: Point[] } {
        const args = new Args();
        const preview: Point[] = [];
        args.values.push(...args.shape.shapeArgs.map((d) => d.default));
        const previewSize = computed(() => ({
                width: (Math.max(1, ...this.preview.map((p) => p.x)) + 
                40) * 10,
                height: (Math.max(1, ...this.preview.map((p) => p.y)) + 
                40) * 10,
            }))
        return { args, preview: preview, previewSize: previewSize };
    }
...
```

Comment: thanks that seems to have got it

Comment: for reference to anyone else hitting this
the computed parameter is part of the options API, and the setup function is part of the composition API, because they are different ways of making components they don't always work together especially when typescript is included in the mix